# Generate pre-signed url for object in s3 bucket and perform 301 redirect in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am facing an issue which I have been unable to solve. I wish to generate a pre signed URL and redirect the user in the front end on that url so that he can download the file. For that reason I added one more trigger on my lambda function and that is an API Gateway. Here is my code:

```
import os
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  url = ""
  for record in event['Records']:
      bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
      file_key = record['s3']['object']['key']
      uri_duration = 90
      s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
      url = s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = 
      {'Bucket': bucket, 
     'Key': file_key}, 
      ExpiresIn = uri_duration)
      print(url)
  return {"location": url }
```

The code is supposed to to save the pre-signed url in the "location", which is then mapped to the API. The problem is that after debugging I realized that this function is run once every time it is called either by the API Gateway or from the s3 bucket. Therefore I would like to ask if someone knows if there is any way to generate a pre-signed url and do a 301 redirect there with any other way? Sorry if my question is obvious I am new to AWS